# jQuery scroll to anchor function on same page, but go directly on different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, scrollto

I have a few lines of jQuery that basically detects anchor links, and scrolls to them:

```
jQuery('a[href*=\\#]').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(this.hash).offset().top - 100}, 500);
});
```

The problem is, when I have anchor links outbound to different pages, they don't even work anymore, because of this code. So essentially I want to alter this code so it only fires same page anchor links (and not for outbound anchor links). I'm assuming it's somewhere in the `a[href*=\\#]`but not quite sure.

So essentially if the `href` starts with a `#` that would mean it is on the same page, otherwise don't use this code block.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [start-with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector for this purpose

```
jQuery('a[href^=\\#]').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop:jQuery(this.hash).offset().top - 100}, 500);
});
```

Comment: This is probably the quickest approach, without having to add classes. If for some reason this approach does create conflict, I suggest adding a dedicated class like `.click-to-scroll`. This way it  won't ever get confused with anchor tags on other pages, unless you add the class to those anchor tags.